# Suspending the JVM for a limited amount of time

Tags: java, jvm

How can I suspend the execution of a JVM for a configurable amount of time, similar to want happens on a full, serial, Garbage Collection? I want to test some edge cases but it's difficult to create the exact pauses I need with manually generating garbage + `System.gc()`.

---

I'm trying to 'freeze' all the threads in the application, to simulate a situation where an application becomes unresponsive, and then resumes execution. The application is part of a cluster, and I'm trying to debug some leave / join / re-join problems.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Would a simple sleep() work ?

Comment: @Romain: see my question update.

Comment: you ended up answering your own question?  :) 

any chance you ever came across the info on how to suspect the JVM itself from within?  I'm in need of that solution right now.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Virtual Machine and suspend its execution outright.

Answer (score 4):

JVM suspend can be done from command line with [jdb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jdb.html):

```
jdb -attach 8787
Initializing jdb ...
> suspend
All threads suspended.
> resume
All threads resumed.
> exit
```

But this requires it to be started with `-Xdebug ...`

There is also [universal way](http://rackerhacker.com/2009/06/15/two-great-signals-sigstop-and-sigcont/) to suspend and resume any process on Linux/Unix:

```
kill -SIGSTOP PID
kill -SIGCONT PID
```

See also [How to suspend/resume a process in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010165/how-to-suspend-resume-a-process-in-windows)

Answer (score 3):

When debugging from Eclipse you can supsend all threads, I guess other debuggers allow to do that too. So you'd need to start your server with JVM debug options and remote connect to it.

In my case (running JBoss) I modify the startup script by adding this line:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%
```

Then in Eclipse, Run -> Debug Configurations -> Remove Java Application -> New

Normally you just need to provide the hostname and the port.

Comment: Thanks, I was considering that. Do you happen to know how I can do that without Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want something that is less invasive, but one approach is to have a controlling thread obtain a lock and then have all the other threads also try to obtain that lock.  Then have the controlling thread sleep for the time you need before giving it up.  A slightly less clumsy version of this would be to use a semaphore with one permit per thread and then have the controlling thread obtain them all, before having all the other threads try to acquire a permit.

As I said that's pretty invasive you'd have to hack that into your code for each thread.

Another approach would be to run your code under a debugger and manually suspend each thread.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I was looking for something which locks all threads, including some which are controlled by third party code.

Comment: A slightly more involved approach might be to use the JPDA api to write your own debugger which enumerates the threads and suspends them.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I did not find anything related to this in jdb. Do you have any pointers on how that can be done?