# Is there a way to freeze JVM intentionally

Tags: java, jvm

I need to freeze JVM when load gets high in order to get memory dump of it. Is there any way to do it?

On Windows machine

Comment: You can have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674292/suspending-the-jvm-for-a-limited-amount-of-time

Comment: 1. Why freezing instead of just getting memory dump? 2. Do you mean heap dump or a process minidump? 3. [PsSuspend](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend) can suspend/resume a process on Windows.

Comment: high load part is so quick that i cant get memory dump at that time. Also i cant edit the code to make it stop. So i thought my option is freezing JVM :)

Comment: I don't see why you can't get memory dump at the time you want. If you can invoke a command to freeze JVM, then you can invoke a command to make a dump. JVM is already "frozen" while dumping is in progress.